# Issue setting up Stripe as the default and always expanded payment method in Magento 2 with Codazon_Unlimited theme

Tags: php, magento, stripe-payments, magento2, magento2.4

I'm using the Codazon_Unlimited theme in my Magento 2 store, and I'm struggling to configure Stripe as the default payment method that is always expanded in the checkout process. Despite my programming skills, Magento proves to be quite challenging.

I have followed the instructions from the Magento documentation, modifying the template file and adding the necessary code to set Stripe as the default and expanded payment method. However, I'm not achieving the desired outcome.

The Stripe payment method is not appearing as selected by default, and it is not expanded, requiring users to manually click on the radio button to expand it.

I have searched for solutions in both the Magento and Codazon_Unlimited documentation, but I couldn't find specific guidance on properly configuring the default and expanded payment method.

In addition to this, I would like to know if there is any way to display the payment method with its options always visible, without having to rely on users clicking the radio button to expand it.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to address this frustrating issue and successfully configure Stripe as the default and always expanded payment method using the Codazon_Unlimited theme.

Comment: If you're using the Stripe Abode Commerce connector ( https://github.com/stripe/stripe-magento2-releases/blob/master/README.md ) then you should review their documentation too, and reach out to their support team if you still need help https://support.stripe.com/contact